# c++ const conundrum

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, constants, extern

I have the following code in 3 files:

*Defines.h*

```
#ifndef Defines_h
extern const unsigned int SIZE;

#endif
```

*Defines.cpp*

```
#include "Defines.h"

const unsigned int SIZE = 10;
```

*Main.cpp*

```
#include "Defines.h"

int main()
{
    int x[SIZE] = {0};
}
```

On compiling I get the error at the array definition line as:

error C2057: expected constant expression and
C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0

Why does this happen, after all I have SIZE which is indeed a constant ?

Comment: I don't think you can do that. The array size needs to be known at compile-time, but it's the linker finding the definition.

Comment: are you trying to initialize all elements of the array to 0?

Comment: @chris - Hmmm yes that could be the reason as SIZE will be resolved at link time only...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `const unsigned int SIZE = 10;` into the header and remove the extern line. With a simple const int value it is safe and harmless to declare it directly in-header.

Answer (score 0):

`const` are implicitly `static`, you need an `extern` even on the `SIZE` definition. includes file will not link because it is looking for a `const unsigned int SIZE` with external linkage.

Comment: _"includes file will not link because it is looking for a `const unsigned int SIZE` with external linkage."_ In this statement, practically everything that can possibly be wrong is wrong.